# AutoFixture customization with OmitAutoProperties not working

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, autofixture

I'm using AutoFixture with NUnit and when I use `OmitAutoProperties` the properties still are being automatically populated. here is how my customization looks like:

```
    public class ContractItemCustomization : ICustomization
    {
        public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
        {
            var orderReceivedContractItem = fixture.Build<ContractItem>()
                                    .OmitAutoProperties()
                                    .With(x => x.Status, new ContractStatus
                                    {
                                        ContractLifecycleStatus = ContractLifecycleStatus.ORDER_RECEIVED
                                    });

            fixture.Customizations.Add(orderReceivedContractItem);
        }
    }
```

Here is how I use my customization:

```
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            fixture = new Fixture().Customize(
                new CompositeCustomization(
                    new ContractItemCustomization()));


            contractItem = fixture.Create<ContractItem>();
        }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after looking deeper in the AutoFixture documentation I found out the solution:

Instead of:

`fixture.Customizations.Add(orderReceivedContractItem);`

I had to do this:

`fixture.Register(() => orderReceivedContractItem.Create());`